# Joining Team site to Teams SharePoint Online

Tags: team-sites, microsoft-teams, spo

I've launched teams from the o365 panel (https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/discover) and want to add a SharePoint Team Site I created earlier. 
I created the SharePoint Team site through SharePoint where you have the option to create a Team Site or Communication Site, both which are Modern sites as far as I understand.

So within Teams 'Join a team with a code' I am trying to add my SharePoint Team Site, however I cant find any way to locate the code, which I assume is retrieved from the existing sites.

Thanks

Comment: earlier team site you created, is it in sharepoint online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add you existing team site with teams by following the below steps

- Open team's application
- Click join or create a teams

[image]

- Then click create team
- Choose "Create a team from an existing Office 365 group"

[image]

- Then select your existing team and click choose team
- then you Existing team site will get associate with teams application

If your existing Team site is not listed while choosing the team site, then your existing site is not proper office 365 group site.

Answer (score 0):

When you send someone a code for joining a team, they can join directly—you won’t get a join request. You can use the code as many times as you want.

If you’re a team owner, go to the team name and click More options  More options button > Manage team. Select the Settings tab > Team code > Generate. Click Copy. Share the code with your invitees however you choose—send the code to a single person via chat or write it on a white board for a whole room full of people.

People can use the code on the Suggested teams screen.

Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-link-or-a-code-for-joining-a-team-11b0de3b-9288-4cb4-bc49-795e7028296f